Cannot transform vectors from viewport to world
I started working on a small raytracer project, and i decided to reuse my already existing openGL renderer to do this, i'm using GLM to manage transforms/positions.
However, i stumbled upon a very annoying issue: when transforming my rays from screen coordinates to world coordinates, i get very much wrong results.
For instance, if i try to transform a vector v(0, 0, 0, 1) from screen to world by doing inverse(viewport * projection * view) * v, i am expecting to retrieve a point at the top left of my camera's near plane, but instead i am getting a point exetremely far away from it.
I don't understand what is happening, since the renderer works very well. I tracked the problem to be either the view() or projection() functions of my camera, but everything looks perfectly fine, i am missing a very important point that i am not aware of.
For reference, the camera class:
#pragma once
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <sprout_engine/shader.h>
#include "inspectable.h"

using namespace glm;

enum CAMERA_DIR
{
    FORWARD,
    BACKWARD,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    UP,
    DOWN
};

struct Plane
{
    glm::vec3 n;
    float d; // distance from origin to nearest point of the plane

    Plane() = default;
    Plane(const glm::vec3& p, const glm::vec3& norm) : n(glm::normalize(norm)), d(glm::dot(n, p)) {}

    inline float getSignedDistanceToPlane(const glm::vec3& p) const { return glm::dot(n, p) - d; };
};

struct Frustum
{
    Plane topFace;
    Plane bottomFace;

    Plane rightFace;
    Plane leftFace;

    Plane farFace;
    Plane nearFace;
};

const float CAMERA_SPEED = 5.f;
const float CAMERA_SENSITIVITY = .1f;

class Camera : public Inspectable
{
protected:
    glm::vec3 pos;
    glm::vec3 dir;
    glm::vec3 up;
    glm::vec3 worldUp;
    glm::vec3 right;

    float m_zNear;
    float m_zFar;
    float m_fov;
    float m_aspectRatio;

    float pitch;
    float yaw;

    glm::mat4 m_view{};
    glm::mat4 m_projection{};

    Frustum m_frustum;

    void update_dir();

public:
    Camera();
    Camera(const glm::vec3 &pos, const glm::vec3 &up, float pitch, float yaw, float p_znear, float p_zfar, float p_fov, float p_aspectRatio);

    void drawInspector() override;

    [[nodiscard]] glm::mat4 view() const;
    [[nodiscard]] glm::mat4 projection() const;

    [[nodiscard]] inline glm::vec3 get_position() const { return pos; };
    [[nodiscard]] inline Frustum getFrustum() const { return m_frustum; };

    void setZNear(float mZNear);
    void setZFar(float mZFar);
    void setFov(float mFov);
    void setAspectRatio(float mAspectRatio);

    void updateView();
    void updateProjection();
    void updateFrustum();

    void process_input(CAMERA_DIR direction, float delta_time);

    void process_mouse_movement(float xoffset, float yoffset);
};

and its implementation:
//
// Created by Bellaedris on 28/04/2024.
//

#include "camera.h"
#include "imgui/imgui.h"

void Camera::update_dir() {
    vec3 new_dir;
    float yawRad = radians(yaw);
    float pitchRad = radians(pitch);
    new_dir.x = std::cos(yawRad) * std::cos(pitchRad);
    new_dir.y = std::sin(pitchRad);
    new_dir.z = std::sin(yawRad) * std::cos(pitchRad);

    dir = normalize(new_dir);
    right = normalize(cross(dir, worldUp));
    up = normalize(cross(right, dir));

    updateView();
}

Camera::Camera()
        : dir(vec3(0., 0., -1.)), pitch(0.), yaw(0.)
{
    pos = vec3(0., 0., 0.);
    worldUp = vec3(0., 1., 0.);

    right = normalize(cross(dir, worldUp));
}

Camera::Camera(const vec3 &pos, const vec3 &up, float pitch, float yaw, float p_znear, float p_zfar, float p_fov,
               float p_aspectRatio)
        : dir(vec3(0., 0., -1.)), pos(pos), worldUp(up), up(up), pitch(pitch), yaw(yaw), m_zNear(p_znear), m_zFar(p_zfar), m_fov(p_fov), m_aspectRatio(p_aspectRatio)
{
    right = normalize(cross(dir, up));
    update_dir();

    updateView();
    updateProjection();
    updateFrustum();
}

glm::mat4 Camera::view() const {
    return m_view;
}

glm::mat4 Camera::projection() const {
    return m_projection;
}

void Camera::setZNear(float mZNear) {
    m_zNear = mZNear;
    updateProjection();
}

void Camera::setZFar(float mZFar) {
    m_zFar = mZFar;
    updateProjection();
}

void Camera::setFov(float mFov) {
    m_fov = mFov;
    updateProjection();
}

void Camera::setAspectRatio(float mAspectRatio) {
    m_aspectRatio = mAspectRatio;
    updateProjection();
}

void Camera::updateView() {
    m_view = glm::lookAt(pos, pos + dir, up);
    updateFrustum();
}

void Camera::updateProjection() {
    m_projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(m_fov), m_aspectRatio, m_zNear, m_zFar);
    updateFrustum();
}

void Camera::updateFrustum() {
    Frustum frustum;
    float halfVSide = std::tan(glm::radians(m_fov) * .5f) * m_zFar; // find the half height of the far plane with trigo
    float halfHSide = halfVSide * m_aspectRatio; // aspect = w / h
    vec3 farPlaneCenter = m_zFar * dir;

    frustum.farFace = { pos + farPlaneCenter, -dir };
    frustum.nearFace = { pos + m_zNear * dir, dir };

    frustum.rightFace = { pos , cross(farPlaneCenter - right * halfHSide, up) };
    frustum.leftFace = { pos , cross(up, farPlaneCenter + right * halfHSide) };

    frustum.topFace = { pos , cross(right, farPlaneCenter - up * halfVSide) };
    frustum.bottomFace = { pos , cross(farPlaneCenter + up * halfVSide, right) };

    m_frustum = frustum;
}

void Camera::process_input(CAMERA_DIR direction, float delta_time) {
    float velocity = CAMERA_SPEED * delta_time;
    switch (direction)
    {
        case FORWARD:
            pos += dir * velocity;
            break;
        case BACKWARD:
            pos -= dir * velocity;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            pos -= right * velocity;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            pos += right * velocity;
            break;
        case UP:
            pos += up * velocity;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            pos -= up * velocity;
            break;
    }
    update_dir();
}

void Camera::process_mouse_movement(float xoffset, float yoffset) {
    xoffset = std::abs(xoffset) <= 1.f ? 0.f : xoffset;
    yoffset = std::abs(yoffset) <= 1.f ? 0.f : yoffset;

    xoffset *= CAMERA_SENSITIVITY;
    yoffset *= CAMERA_SENSITIVITY;

    yaw += xoffset;
    pitch += yoffset;

    // to avoid the lookAt matrix to flip
    if (pitch > 89.f)
        pitch = 89.f;
    if (pitch < -89.f)
        pitch = -89.f;

    update_dir();
}

void Camera::drawInspector() {
    if(ImGui::TreeNode("Camera"))
    {
        if(ImGui::InputFloat3("Position", glm::value_ptr(pos)))
        {
            update_dir();
        }
        if (ImGui::InputFloat("Pitch", &pitch))
        {
            update_dir();
        }
        if (ImGui::InputFloat("Yaw", &yaw))
        {
            update_dir();
        }
        if (ImGui::InputFloat("FoV", &m_fov))
        {
            updateProjection();
        }
        ImGui::TreePop();
    }
}

The function that gives me the viewport matrix (m_width and m_height are the dimensions of the window)
glm::mat4 SproutApp::viewport() const {
    float w = (float)m_width / 2.f;
    float h = (float)m_height / 2.f;

    return {
            w,  0.,  0.,  0,
            0,  h,  0,   0,
            0., 0., .5f, 0,
            w,  h,  .5f,   1
            };
}

And the piece of code that produces wrong transformation:
m_model = Model(resources_path + "models/cornell-box.obj");
        cam = new Camera({0, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 0}, 0, -90.f, 0.1f, 100.f, 70.f, (float)width() / (float)height());
        m_shader = Shader("texture.vs", "texture.fs");
        m_debugShader = Shader("default.vs", "default.fs");

        m_lines = std::make_unique<LineRenderer>(cam);

        glm::mat4 camToWorld = glm::inverse(cam->view());
        glm::mat4 screenToWorld = glm::inverse(viewport() * cam->projection() * cam->view());

        m_lines->addLine({screenToWorld * glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1)}, {screenToWorld * glm::vec4(0, 0, 1, 1)});
        m_lines->addLine({screenToWorld * glm::vec4(width(), 0, 0, 1)}, {screenToWorld * glm::vec4(width(), 0, 1, 1)});
        m_lines->addLine({screenToWorld * glm::vec4(0, height(), 0, 1)}, {screenToWorld * glm::vec4(0, height(), 1, 1)});
        m_lines->addLine({screenToWorld * glm::vec4(width(), height(), 0, 1)}, {screenToWorld * glm::vec4(width(), height(), 1, 1)});
```


why do you have a viewport, view and projeciton matrix? what is the viewport supposed to be? You only need the view (world to camera) and the projection (viewspace to clip space)

Viewport converts clip space to screen space. I use it because i need to send a ray per pixel of the screen, if my viewport's dimension are x*y, i think it is convenient to be able to loop over x and y when sending my rays.
It would indeed be possible to just use the clipspace, but i think it is less clear and my method has no overhead whatsoever (the viewport matrix is computed only once).
